# Android custom listview with checkbox?

Tags: android, mobile

I am new to android and I am starting a new Application in which I have to list down some users. The list includes image, name and mobile number and the list also include a checkbox. The checkbox has to be enable only when I click on a button like 'Download'. So far I have the listview with checkbox. My question is how can I enabled the checkbox only when I click on 'download' button? And also how can I capture the state of Checkbox?  Any help will be appriciate. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

try looking in this tutorial http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters. This is where I lernt how to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom listview in Android.

- Fist learn the basics of ListView in [Andriod here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) Then learn
- about custom [ListView here](http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/customizing-android-listview-item-layout/)
- Then learn more about ListView  [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) and also [here](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/create-application-launcher-as-a-list/)

Then implement your own listview

Wish you all the best.